# Python Recursion doesn`t return anything

Tags: python, recursion

Here is a small snippet of code I wrote, which surprisingly doesn`t return anything:

```
class Solution:
    def findTheWinner(self, n: int, k: int) -> int:
        lst = [i for i in  range(1,n+1)]
        
        def recur(lst):
            if len(lst) == 1:
                return lst[0]
            else:

                recur(lst[k:]+lst[:k-1])

        return recur(lst)

n=5
k=2

S=Solution()

S.findTheWinner(n,k)
```

Comment: In the `else` block you don't execute a `return`, so yes, it doesn't return anything in that case (`None`).